# Obtener 3 nombres y mostrarlos ordenados

Tags: javascript, array

tengo un problema, resulta que en mi codigo, tengo definidos tres nombres con el Array, pero como le puedo hacer para que mi programa solicite primero los tres nombres, es decir que el usuario escriba 3 nombres los que sean, que los ordene alfabeticamente y luego los muestre como resultado ya ordenados.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Caracteres</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
    body    {
background-color:#DBDFDB; 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<font color="#030303" face="georgia" size="5"> 
<center>
    <TABLE BORDER=3 width="1000" height="50">
    <TR><TD>
        <font face="georgia" size="30">
    <MARQUEE SCROLLAMOUNT=10 BEHAVIOR="alternate"><b>Programa para calcular caracteres</b></MARQUEE>
    </font>
    </TD></TR>
    </TABLE>

<script type="text/javascript">

var nombres = new Array("Andres", "Juan", "Carlos");
nombres.sort();

for (var i=0; i<nombres.length; i++) {
    document.write(nombres[i]);
}

</script>

</script>
</center>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

texto en negrita

Answer (score 0):

trata esto en vez de que sea automático.
Creo que la solución seria que en este código que acabo de escribir Guiándome de los que tienes

```js
function validar(){
  var nombre1 = $('#nombre1').val();
  var nombre2 = $('#nombre2').val();
  var nombre3 = $('#nombre3').val();
  
  if(nombre1 == '' || nombre2 == '' || nombre3 =='' ){
    
    alert('llenar todo los campos requerido');
    
  }else{
  var nombres = new Array(nombre1, nombre2, nombre3);
  nombres.sort();

    for (var i=0; i<nombres.length; i++) {
      document.write(nombres[i]);
  }
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<font color="#030303" face="georgia" size="5"> 
<center>
    <TABLE BORDER=3 width="1000" height="50">
    <TR><TD>
        <font face="georgia" size="30">
    <MARQUEE SCROLLAMOUNT=10 BEHAVIOR="alternate"><b>Programa para calcular caracteres</b></MARQUEE>
    <input type='text' name='nombre1' id='nombre1'>
    <input type='text' name='nombre2' id='nombre2'>
    <input type='text' name='nombre3' id='nombre3'>
      
      <button type='button' onclick='validar()'>SEN VALIDATION</button
    </font>
    </TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
```

Comment: Si tienes dudas estaré por estos rumbos

Comment: Andale exactamente gama984, es lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias ingeniero! por este apoyo, mil gracias.